# Error using fontspec v2.4a and unicode-math

Tags: fontspec, scaling, unicode-math

Compiling the following example with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabular}{c}
  Foo
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

yields the error

```
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   dimexpr 
l.11 \begin{tabular}
                    {c}
```

when using fontspec **v2.4a** from TeX Live 2014.

Replacing `11pt` by `10pt` or `12pt`, or removing `\small`, the example compiles without problems.

Comment: The bug is already known: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/177. Add in the meantime `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` before `\documentclass..`.

Comment: I'll be uploading a fix to CTAN in the next day or two.

Comment: Version 0.7f of `unicode-math` should now be available from CTAN; when it propagates into TeX Live / MiKTeX hopefully this problem will be fixed.

Comment: The issue was fixed in unicode-math 0.7f. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in the version of the software, solved with an upgrade.