# Lots of errors in default friggeri resumé cv

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, cv, friggeri-cv

I get lots of errors when compiling (XeLaTeX, from up-to-date MiKTeX 2.9 x64, TeXstudio 2.8.0, Windows 8 x64) the friggeri-cv template. Download it here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv .

The errors:

- Missing endcsname inserted
- You can't use `dimexpr` in math mode. \begin{entrylist}
- Extra endcsname. \begin{entrylist}
- Missing font identifier. \begin{entrylist}
- Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts. \end{entrylist}

All errors show up multiple times and I can not find any clues on their origin when looking around on the internet. The strange thing is that this CV did compile without errors in the past and I have adapted it for my personal use. My adaptation also compiled without problems.

Now, I got many errors when compiling my CV (it has been a month or so since the last compile). So I tried compiling the default template to see whether it was my bad or not: I get the same errors. It appears either the template is not working any-more, or my (Xe)LaTeX installation is broken/bugged.

I have also tried changing the fonts in the .cls file to Arial, but no luck there (I have Helvetica Neue installed, tough, and the font has worked for me before with this template).

Have there been updates to packages in the last month, making the template unusable? Or is there a problem with my PC?

Any help or thoughts are appreciated! Thanks.

There are no errors when compiling when I disable alle `entrylist` environments and the line containing the `$\varheartsuit$`.

As requested in a comment below: I can compile a pretty simple .tex file with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` without errors, so both compilers can do their job.

Another request from the comments: the .log file containing the errors I get when running `xelatex` on the default Friggeri template:

- .log file: https://copy.com/WloGkamcE0Uf
- .pdf file: https://copy.com/2WyARiQe439U
- what it should look like: http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/10/cv_10.pdf

Comment: Without a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551), we cannot foresee what are the problems with your document. Did you try to compile the (non-edited) template recently?

Comment: Yes, I did compile the default template. I thought this was clear from my post, but it appears this is not the case. So I edited the post to clarify I did also compile the default untouched template and got the same errors.

Comment: "The strange thing is that this CV has compiled error-free for me in the past" : in the present too, so. + "borked" = "broken"? + I can compile the fresh, untouched template (`This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.7.9)`).

Comment: Can you compile any other `.tex` file, with `pdflatex`, with `XeLaTex`?

Comment: @Clément I can compile .tex files with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` error free. I don't know where it goes wrong. See my edit in the first post for the MWE that compiles correctly. I have also edited the "borked", which is slang for broken, indeed. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Erik A minimal example of a broken document is necessary, too.

Comment: I did'nt know the expression "borked", I don't mind slang. + you don't have to add a MWE of what you can compile : simply remove it, and remove the "Or is there a problem with my PC?" question : you now answered that part. + maybe you should copy/paste the `.log` file resulting of the compilation of the untouched template.

Comment: @Clément & egreg, thanks, you're being helpful. I've included the .log file in the main post now.

Comment: @Erik The `Missing \endcsname` error is due to a bug in `fontspec` that has been solved by now: update the package with MiKTeX's package manager. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186690/error-using-fontspec-v2-4a-and-unicode-math

Comment: @egreg, still no luck. I guessed it was some package error, so I updated my entire MiKTeX installation, including all packages. I still get the errors. To be sure, I also used both the MiKTeX Package Manager and the MiKTeX Updater to check whether or not there are package updates. No updates available, so I use the most recent package versions. I also uninstalled and reinstalled the `fontspec` package. I still get the errors. I've looked up the `fontspec` version the Package Manager tells me I have: v2.4a. The same version as the most recent version available on ctan.org/pkg/fontspec . :(

Comment: Still a minimal TeX code example is missing.

Comment: @egreg, ah I see the fix in the link you posted now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was wrong: it's `unicode-math` the culprit: the current version is `2014/06/30 v0.7f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@egreg posted the solution:

`\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` needs to be put before `\documentclass{...}` until an update fixes `unicode-math`.

This has fixed my problem.